# Programatically and reliably retrieve the path to the go executable in container without 'which' with Go

Tags: docker, go

How can I retrieve the path to the `go` binary in a container that does not have `which` *programatically*?

One option would be to execute `which go` as follows:

```
bytes, err := exec.Command("which", "go").Output()
```

However, I would like to not depend on `which` being available. Does go provide any in-built mechanism to retrieve this and if not, what is the alternative apart from having the user pass in the path themselves?

Comment: have you tried to install `which` or you don't want to depend on it in general ?

Comment: Do you mean this image: [hub.docker.com/_/golang](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang)? (Because the one you've shared doesn't have the `go` binary). A quick test with `golang:1.12-alpine`: `which go` gives `/usr/local/go/bin/go`.

Comment: @tgogos This is indeed correct, I have amended the link, thanks. Maybe the alpine specifically isn't the issue then, but relying on `which`. Thanks, I've updated the question to remove the alpine, it was my finding from an alternative alpine. The question still stands :)

Comment: @MostafaHussein I need to not depend on `which` in general.

Comment: You might already tried this https://tip.golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable Does it work as expected ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein This returns the path of the *file*, after building it could be something in `/tmp`, but it's not the path to the `go` executable.

Comment: Use [exec.LookPath](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath)

Comment: @Peter Excellent, this works! Many thanks - fancy putting it in an answer? I'd be happy to upvote and tick :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page of `which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which):

> Which takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints to stdout the full path of the executables that would have been executed when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt. It does this by searching for an executable or script in the directories listed in the environment variable PATH using the same algorithm as bash(1).

[Go's `os/exec.LookPath` function](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath) is very close to this functionality:

> LookPath searches for an executable named file in the directories named by the PATH environment variable. If file contains a slash, it is tried directly and the PATH is not consulted. The result may be an absolute path or a path relative to the current directory.

Use [`path/filepath.Abs`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) if you need a guaranteed absolute path.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter!

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect this to be the best answer, but it is one that I just found. I was hoping for more of a go-specific one, but in the meantime [type](https://ss64.com/bash/type.html) in linux is a default built-in one available in bash and sh (alpine).

You can test this yourself by running `type type` which yields:

> type is a shell builtin

The usage in `go` would look like this:

```
b, err := exec.Command("type", "go").Output()

if err != nil {
    /* 'type' is not available on the O/S */
}

goPath := strings.TrimPrefix(strings.TrimSuffix(string(b), "\n"), "go is ")
```

The reason the `Trim` functions are required is because the output would look like this:

> go is /usr/local/go/bin/go\n

This isn't the nicest way of going about it, but it works.

Comment: You're not executing a shell built-in if you're not executing a shell, though `/usr/bin/type` does do the same thing. Doesn't [`exec.LookPath`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath) do what you want?